# I am getting my error in setting up cardview and recyclerview dependencies

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

I'm getting an error in my Android Studio as my compile sdk version is 26 and build tool version is 26.0.2.

The error is that I am unable to add CardView and RecyclervView dependencies because they are available in 28.0.0- alpha1 in my library and showing error in build If I manually put them in dependencies!

What am I suppose to do?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please be a bit more specific when asking a question: *What have you tried so far with a code example? ([I downvoted because there is no code](http://idownvotedbecau.se/nocode/))* / *What do you expect?* / *What error do you get?* **For Help take a look at "[How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)"**

Comment: Never use `+` in your dependency versions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:26.0.1'
```

Also add this to your main all project level `build.gradle` file under `allprojects()`

```
maven {
    url "https://maven.google.com"
 }
```

Comment: Hi Deep,, I tried this but appcompat showing error,

Comment: Please elaborate more for your problem, check and try updated answer as well